# 'favicon.ico' FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3]

Tags: html, favicon

How to avoid the 'favicon.ico' not found error in below flask code? I searched few favicon.ico issues but could not resolve this one.

```
 @app.route('/<path:req_path>')
 def dir_listing(req_path):
    abs_path = os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, req_path)
    # Check if path is a file and serve
    if os.path.isfile(abs_path):
        return send_file(abs_path, mimetype="application/json")
    # Show directory contents
    files = os.listdir(abs_path)
    return render_template('file_list.html', files=files)
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Upload new File</title>

<hr>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />
<h1>{{message}}</h1>

<form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <p><input type=file name=file>
    <input type=submit value=Upload>
</form>

 <ul>
    {% for file in file_list %}
    <li><a href="{{ file }}">{{ file }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
 </ul>
```

file_list.html-

```
  <ul>
      {% for file in files %}
         <li>
           <a href="{{ file }}">{{ file }}</a>
         </li>
      {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

Comment: Well, maybe, the favicon file is not present?

Comment: where do i check that favicon file?

Comment: try to inspect the browser and find the link in your favicon tag. It's possible if you entered the wrong path

Comment: @miruku sheki    By 'path',  do you mean variable 'file' in my file_list.html code?

Comment: By default a browser always look for a `/favicon.ico` when opening a website, you would need to serve a favicon file there to get rid of that error. You can also customize the path [following this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/The_head_metadata_in_HTML#Adding_custom_icons_to_your_site)

Comment: @WilliamChong it helps. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default a browser always look for a `/favicon.ico` when opening a website, you would need to serve a favicon file there to get rid of that error.

You can also customize the path following [this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/The_head_metadata_in_HTML#Adding_custom_icons_to_your_site)